# Image don't shown in Django LFS

Tags: django, image, encoding

I've added image to product, but it not shown in product preview. Error message appears: "The request content cannot be loaded. Please try again later".
Web-page is located in localhost, DB is in UTF8_general_ci (MySQL), Django 1.8, Python 2.7.
Also when I try to open an attachement (i've put image there), I recieve an error, traceback il below that post:
Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/media/files/book1.png

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('lfs_theme',
 'compressor',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'django.contrib.redirects',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django_countries',
 'pagination',
 'reviews',
 'portlets',
 'lfs.addresses',
 'lfs.caching',
 'lfs.cart',
 'lfs.catalog',
 'lfs.checkout',
 'lfs.core',
 'lfs.criteria',
 'lfs.customer',
 'lfs.customer_tax',
 'lfs.discounts',
 'lfs.export',
 'lfs.gross_price',
 'lfs.mail',
 'lfs.manage',
 'lfs.marketing',
 'lfs.manufacturer',
 'lfs.net_price',
 'lfs.order',
 'lfs.page',
 'lfs.payment',
 'lfs.portlet',
 'lfs.search',
 'lfs.shipping',
 'lfs.supplier',
 'lfs.tax',
 'lfs.tests',
 'lfs.utils',
 'lfs.voucher',
 'lfs_contact',
 'lfs_order_numbers',
 'localflavor',
 'postal',
 'paypal.standard.ipn',
 'paypal.standard.pdt')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
 'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/stp/Рабочий стол/lfs-installer/eggs/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/stp/Рабочий стол/lfs-installer/eggs/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/views/static.py" in serve
  54.     fullpath = os.path.join(document_root, newpath)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py" in join
  80.             path += '/' + b

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /media/files/book1.png
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that media root path contains non-ASCII characters, such as *"Рабочий стол"*.

Posible solutions:

- Move your project to ASCII-only (non-Cyrillic in your case) path
- Use Python3 instead 2, which not have this Unicode problems
- Change `MEDIA_ROOT` setting to Unicode string, e.g. `u'/home/stp/Рабочий стол/myproject/media/'`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that :)

Answer (score 0):

To get image and override ANSII encoding I've done following:

- Added string `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of the
  settings.py in my LFS;
- As Mr. Tikhonov said, changed `MEDIA_ROOT` string

After that images started to load normally.